# Replacing a Dataframe entry inside a nested Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran into an issue recently doing some Dataframe manipulations. My issue can be showcased with the following code snippet (I'll explain the goal after)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(columns=("A","B"))
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))))


a["A"] = [pd.DataFrame({"x": np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), "y": np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])})] # We fill in column A with a DataFrame containing keys

a.B = [pd.DataFrame({"x": np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), "y": np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])})]  # Same as for A but different way of writing it. It works

c = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), "y": np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), "z": np.array([11,12,13,14,15])}) #This is a new dataframe


a.B = c # I want to completely replace dataframe in entry B by the dataframe c. This fails
```

This is probably a bit trivial but I'm always struggling with pandas.

This code snippet showcases my scenario. I want to completely replace the data under key B in the main dataframe "a" with another dataframe. Meaning that a.B would show me c content.

It will fail on the following line, raising this error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

```
a.B = c
```

Is there a specific method on dataframe for doing this ? I dug a lot and couldn't find the solution yet.

I tried looking into Pandas methods like replace, insert etc...
Even asked ChatGPT for inspiration. To no avail
Couldn't find the same question on SO either.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
a.at[0, 'B'] = c
```

Then:

```
print(a.at[0, 'B'])

   x  y   z
0  0  5  11
1  1  6  12
2  2  7  13
3  3  8  14
4  4  9  15
```

Note that storing objects in a DataFrame is not a good practice, this is even worse storing DataFrames! You might want to consider using a single DataFrame with a MultiIndex.

Comment: Thanks a lot mozway. I'll look into multi index in more details, for now I fail to see how it could improve the situation.